# Drupella form api

Tags: entities

I have looked everywhere but can't find the answer to this question.
I am using Drupella File Manager. All is working well but I have this custom form I have made. I need to make this file field I have use the Drupella FM.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

My code is:

```
$form['site_image'] = array(
  '#type' => 'file',
  //'#default_widget' => array('dfm_filefield_on' => true),
  '#name' => 'site_image',
  '#title' => t('Site image'),
  '#size' => 40,
  '#description' => t('Select your image'),
  '#upload_location' => 'public://media'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-drupal product. But if you're using this sandbox module:
https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/Drupella/2008504

Then the project directions simply say:

> Enable Drupella FM for File Field module if you want to select files from Drupella FM for your image/file fields. You must check the Allow users to select files from Drupella FM for this field option in your field's configuration page.

If you're not using this sandbox module and trying to do this yourself. I recommend you try the sandbox module.

Comment: I am using this. I want to turn a managed_file field into using this drupella field. Do you know how to do this? I have got it working the way you said but I need it with the form api.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes the Form API and Field API are not the same thing. I'm not sure how to make it work with a `managed_file` form element. it appears it's not designed to work that way.